# Keycloak javascript example logout after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I have been playing with the example provided by Keycloak [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/js-console/README.md) but when clicking the login button I'm logged out after 5 secs :(

Also, between those 5 seconds, if I manage to click the refresh Token button, I'm also logged out after that action.

I have created the realm they supply [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/js-console/example-realm.json) but still the same ...

I have just changed the bit of code to point to my keycloak server

```
var keycloak = Keycloak({
  "realm" : "example",
  "auth-server-url" : "https://XXXXXX/auth",
  "ssl-required" : "external",
  "resource" : "js-console",
  "public-client" : true
});
```

Can you please point me in the right direction if I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you!

[image: result_image]

Comment: have you checked the console for errors ? in poarticular if a request comes back as negative ?

Comment: I have seen that response to a refresh token request are returned with status code 400 and following message . {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid refresh token"}   data sent is :  
 grant_type: refresh_token
refresh_token: undefined
client_id: js-console and in console  [KEYCLOAK] Refreshing token: token expired
sse-hooks.js:1 [KEYCLOAK] Failed to refresh token

Comment: try logging in with preserve log anda see if there is a failed request before that oo

Comment: @jonathanHeindl when the iframe tries to refreshToken I see this message in the console _[KEYCLOAK] Refreshing token: token expired_ and then _[KEYCLOAK] Failed to refresh token_. I have deactivated the use of iframes by adding `checkLoginIframe: false` to the init config and **it works**. So I assume there is bug happening when using the iframe ... tnx!

Comment: Have you tried to restart your Keycloak server?

Comment: @GonzaloFJ I just had the same issue with keycloak-adapter 6.0.1 and can confirm that it works, once I add `checkLoginIframe: false` to the initial config. Thanks for that. Did you find an open bug/bugfix on the Keycloak page, or do you know if this is already fixed in some later version?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue once, and it was related to the `checkLoginIframe` method (`checkLoginIframeInterval` actually, which has a 5 seconds timeframe by default).

Please try setting it to `false` in your init options, as described [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/securing_apps/#session-status-iframe)

(I know this thread is kind of old, but it might help someone in the future!)